# Multiple UIBarButton items

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am failing to set up few UIBarButton items using Interface builder.

Here is my hierarchy in my interface builder:

```
View controller:
    View:
         TableView
    Navigation Item:
         BarButtonItem:
              Button on left
         BarButtonItem:
              Button on right
```

The problem is I can't add more than one button on `BarButtonItem`, trying to just drag another button gets the first one overwriten..

To get a bit of clearer view, I have two buttons now one on right one on left. Both of them working great. And the problem is to get like another button on the right side.

I hope the question is clear enough, if you have any questions please do ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting Button in BarButton. Try like this.

```
Navigation Item:
     BarButtonItem:
          Button on left
     BarButtonItem:
          View: // Stuff on right
               Button one
               Button two
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it in Interface Builder, but you can definitely do it programatically.

For iOS 5.0 and above, you can add your UIBarButtonItems to *rightBarButtonItems* (which Interface Builder doesn't expose).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[barButtonItem, barButtonItem2];
}
```

For pre-iOS 5, it's a little harder. You will first have to add the barButtonItems to a UIToolbar, then set the rightBarButtonItem to a barButtonItem with that UIToolbar as its custom view.

Comment: Sorry, i knew it was possible to do programatically, but wish to get it done via interface builder to save some time. Accepted answer is the right solution to my question, but thank you for your time looking to this.